# Is rand() time-dependent in php?

Tags: php, random

Let we explain what I mean.

Some time ago, while writing a program in c#, I've made following mistake:

```
int Randomize()
{
    Random r=new Random();
    return  r.Next(0,10);
}
```

in c#, this is a mistake, because, called several  times in a row, this function will return the same value. This is because Random constructor uses time seed, and the time difference between calls was too low (took me an hour to find that one :) ).

Now I'm using `rand(...)` in php, and I need for the output to always be different, even if 2 scripts are executed at the same time.

Do I have to do something to get this result, or is it designed to work this way?

Comment: Just let it work, though mt_rand() is better than rand()

Comment: Good question. I can't answer it specifically in detail, but the accepted PRNG of choice these days is `mt_rand`, not `rand`.

Comment: Good one but i think in your case it is hard to ensure the output to be different ,even if two scripts are executed at the same time

Comment: My understanding is that PHP uses the underlying system's rand() functionality.  You *could* (although I wouldn't advise it) play around with seeding the PRNG with some combination of the client IP and current time, but there are better PRNG implementations, including the [mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister)-based implementation `mt_rand` that has been mentioned

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the `rand()` and also `mt_rand()` calls `srand()` and `mt_srand()` to produce always random results.
But here's an interesting post on php.net:

> Note that the automatic seeding seems to be done with the current
>   number of seconds which means you can get the same results for several
>   runs on a fast server.  Either call srand() yourself with a more
>   frequently changing seed or use mt_rand() which doesn't appear to
>   suffer from the problem.

So, just call `srand` more frequently or `mt_rand`.

Comment: though not php, but still a good read for why automatic seeding maybe isn't the best approach. http://baagoe.com/en/RandomMusings/javascript/

Answer (score 4):

About `mt_rand()` function...

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php

> As of PHP 4.2.0, there is no need to seed the random number generator with srand() or mt_srand() as this is now done automatically.
>
> (For PHP 5.2.1) The Mersenne Twister implementation in PHP now uses a new seeding algorithm by Richard Wagner. Identical seeds no longer produce the same sequence of values they did in previous versions. This behavior is not expected to change again, but it is considered unsafe to rely upon it nonetheless.

Here is [link](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/ewhat-is-mt.html), with description of the "**Mersenne Twister(MT)**" pseudorandom number generating algorithm (and [implementations](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/c-lang.html) in C, C++, C#)

[Here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c) you can find implementation of this function in PHP 5

And in `php_rand.h` I found this:

```
#ifdef PHP_WIN32
#define GENERATE_SEED() (((long) (time(0) * GetCurrentProcessId())) ^ ((long) (1000000.0 * php_combined_lcg(TSRMLS_C))))
#else
#define GENERATE_SEED() (((long) (time(0) * getpid())) ^ ((long) (1000000.0 * php_combined_lcg(TSRMLS_C))))
#endif
```

So now you can see, that random functions in PHP relies on `time` function...

Comment: Also check out `lcg.c`. It depends on the time **once** if it is not seeded already. By definition the lcg will produce a new random value after each call, and it does not depend on the time function for each call.