# Random function producing duplicate results

Tags: php

I'm working on a script to install sample data into a database. I have a script I coded I call "Generic Data Generator". This PHP file includes a variety of functions to generate random data.

Example function:

```
// Random number generator.
function gdg_number( $number_start, $number_end ) {

    return rand( $number_start, $number_end );
}
```

Example query:

```
function gdg_values( $results ) {

    $values = "";

    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $results; $i++) {
        $values .= "
            '" . gdg_sentence(3,12) . "',
            '" . gdg_multi_paragraphs(1,5,5,8,4,17) . "',
            '" . gdg_multi_paragraphs(1,5,5,8,4,17) . "',
            '" . gdg_number(100,900) . "." . gdg_number(00,99) . "',
            '" . gdg_number(1,20) . "',
            '" . gdg_number(0,50) . "',
            '" . gdg_string(10,10) . "',
            '0'
        ), (";
    }

    return $values;
}

$value = gdg_values( 100 );
$values = substr( $value, 0, -4);
```

The problem I'm experiencing is when I view the MySQL table after I use the script to insert multiple rows, I notice there is duplicate data entries. Entire rows have the same values for each column.

What could cause the `gdg_values()` to produce identical results every 3 rows? (Notice, it does this even if I manually copy/paste the `$values` repeatedly directly into the MySQL query.

Here is the full `generic_data_generator.php` file.

http://pastebin.com/jjRF8SZd

Here is the full `products.php` file which is included in the install script for the database to install sample data into the products MySQL table.

http://pastebin.com/TtkstXgS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated at [Is rand() time-dependent in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203770/is-rand-time-dependent-in-php):

> Note that the automatic seeding seems to be done with the current number of seconds which means you can get the same results for several runs on a fast server. Either call srand() yourself with a more frequently changing seed or use mt_rand() which doesn't appear to suffer from the problem.

Therefore, you can either use:

```
function gdg_number( $number_start, $number_end ) {
    return mt_rand( $number_start, $number_end );
}
```

Or, you can use:

```
function gdg_number( $number_start, $number_end ) {
    srand();
    return rand( $number_start, $number_end );
}
```

Both of which *should* create a different random value more often.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but probably too long for a comment.

Make sure that your text fields are properly escaped. I don't know what your text generating functions are doing but their output needs to be run through `mysql_real_escape_string` (actually, you should be using the `mysqli` functions instead).

Your `product_price` field is an integer but you are inputting a decimal number.

The function `gdg_number` in not needed since it just returns `rand` with exactly the same arguments. Kill that function and just use `rand`.

Use 0 instead of 00. OK, it probably makes no difference but a leading 0 means octal.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that column. I decided to change decimal columns to just TINYTEXT. Easier to handle the numbers with PHP.